# Passing arguments to Hadoop mappers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using **new Hadoop API** and looking for a way to pass some parameters (few strings) to mappers.
**How can I do that?**

[This solutions works for old API](http://www.hongliangjie.com/2011/01/16/passing-parameters-and-arguments-to-mapper-and-reducer-in-hadoop/):

```
JobConf job = (JobConf)getConf();
job.set("NumberOfDocuments", args[0]);
```

Here, “`NumberOfDocuments`” is the name of parameter and its value is read from “`args[0]`“, a command line argument. Once you set this arguments, you can retrieve its value in reducer or mapper as follows:

```
private static Long N;
public void configure(JobConf job) {
     N = Long.parseLong(job.get("NumberOfDocuments"));
}
```

Note, the tricky part is that you cannot set parameters like this:

```
Configuration con = new Configuration();
con.set("NumberOfDocuments", args[0]);
```

Comment: both new and old methods are here: http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/11/passing-parameters-to-mappers-and.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the main method set the required parameter as below or using the [-D command line option](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#Generic_Options) while running the job.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("test", "123");

Job job = new Job(conf);
```

In the mapper/reducer get the parameter as

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
String param = conf.get("test");
```

Comment: and if we want to pass an integer parameter to the mapper?

Comment: VTT - the Configuration object has type-safe setters: setBoolean/setDouble/setEnum/etc... there are corresponding getters as well.

Comment: I am trying to set an array but i cant is there any other way i could do this?