# Getting job configuration in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I wrote some mapreduce code using the mapred import instead of mapreduce (I followed the [example](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) of WordCount for hadoop 1)
I need to get some parameters that I saved in the job configuration. I read about [configuration get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244474/passing-arguments-to-hadoop-mappers) when using mapreduce, but I did all my development using mapred and these two imports are conflicting. Is there a way to get the job configuration in the mapper using mapred?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Mapper`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html) Javadoc:

> Mapper implementations can access the JobConf for the job via the JobConfigurable.configure(JobConf) and initialize themselves.

And as [`JobConf`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html) extends [`Configuration`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) you can access all the properties from the.

To make this accessible to your `map()` calls you could create a `JobConf` variable in your class and set it in your `configure()` so that when your `map()` calls run you can access it from there.

Comment: But since I don't have the context in the map arguments, is there a way to know which JobConf applies like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244474/passing-arguments-to-hadoop-mappers ?